# When I try multiprocessing, multiple windows show up

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pygame, python-3.3

I'm trying to create a pong game for my first Pygame game. I'm very new to Pygame and relatively new to Python. So far I only have the two bumpers on either side. Here is the code I have so far:

```
import pygame, sys, os
from pygame.locals import *

from multiprocessing import Process


window = pygame.display.set_mode((600,400))
pygame.display.set_caption("Pong")
screen = pygame.display.get_surface()

pongBackground = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/LN/Desktop/PongBackground.png")
pongHitter = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/LN/Desktop/PongHitter.png")
pongHitter = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/LN/Desktop/PongHitter.png")
pongBall = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/LN/Desktop/PongBall.png")


pygame.init()


class hitter():
    """moves the pong hitter with arrow keys"""

    def _init_(self):
        screen.blit(pongBackground, (0,0))
        self.position = pongHitter.get_rect()

        pygame.display.update()

    def goTo(self, coord):
        screen.blit(pongHitter,coord)
        self.position = self.position.move(coord)
        pygame.display.update()   

    def moveUp(self):
        for i in range(1):
            screen.blit(pongBackground, self.position, self.position)
            self.position = self.position.move(0, -1)
            screen.blit(pongHitter, self.position)
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(10)
    def moveDown(self):
        for i in range(1):
            screen.blit(pongBackground, self.position, self.position)
            self.position = self.position.move(0, 1)
            screen.blit(pongHitter, self.position)
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(10)


hitterA=hitter()
hitterB=hitter()
hitterA._init_()
hitterB._init_()
hitterA.goTo((5,200))
hitterB.goTo((590,200))


pygame.key.set_repeat(1,1)
contin=True
def inputLeft():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_UP]:
                hitterA.moveUp()
            elif pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_DOWN]:
                hitterA.moveDown()
            elif pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_ESCAPE]:
                sys.exit(0)

def inputRight():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_w]:
                hitterB.moveUp()
            elif pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_s]:
                hitterB.moveDown()
            elif pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_ESCAPE]:
                sys.exit(0)

if __name__=='__main__':
    p = Process(target=inputLeft)
    p.start()
    p.join()
    p2 = Process(target=inputRight)
    p2.start()
    p2.join()
```

Now I'm trying to get it so that both bumpers can move simultaneously. I've tried multiprocessing as you can see above, but it creates different window with each process. How can I get everything to display on one window? Thanks! By the way, this python 3.3.

Comment: You can't share a single Pygame interface across multiple processes (not simply, anyway).  Why are you using multiprocessing?

Answer (score 2):

multi processing is the wrong approach

give wasd to one hitter and the arrows keys to another then for youre keypress statments make it so that wasd moves one paddle and the arrows move the other

here is what your mainloop should look like instead of having two:

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_UP]:
            hitterA.moveUp()

        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_DOWN]:
            hitterA.moveDown()

        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_w]:
            hitterB.moveUp()

        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_s]:
            hitterB.moveDown()

        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_ESCAPE]:
            sys.exit(0)
```

there is no need for multiprocessing it will work just fine without it

your code looks great but just get rid of the multiprocessing

here is a pretty good example of a pong game with pygame you can use it to help you out

[Pygame Pong Example](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/tom/MakeGames.html)

Comment: That was actually my original design. The problem with it is that when you move one bumper, then try moving the other, the first bumper stops. That's why I tried multiprocessing.

Comment: so what happens if you push w and up at the same time

Comment: The other bumper stops because you are using an if-elif structure. So if it goes into ONE of the if statements, its not going to even bother testing the conditions for the other if statements. You need to have SEPARATE if statements for hitterA and hitterB. You do not need multiprocessing or even multithreading for this. Just separate your if statements.

Comment: If I'm holding w, then hold up, the first bumper (activated through w) stops moving.

Comment: @Shashanka Gupta, would you mind showing me an example of this? I'm still a little bit confused.

Comment: if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_UP]: hitterA.moveUp()

elif pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_DOWN]: hitterA.moveDown()

if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_w]:
    hitterB.moveUp()

elif pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_s]:
    hitterB.moveDown()

if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_ESCAPE]:
    sys.exit(0)

Comment: why not just use if statements then

Comment: elif is short for "else if". you don't want that in every case. That's what's stopping you from moving both player's paddles at once :P

Comment: Sweet thanks Shashanka Gupta! There's just one problem. When both bumpers are moving, they seem to move at half speed. Do you know why this could be happening?

Comment: I edited my answer and i tested it and it works change the `elif`s to `if`s

Comment: Too speed up the paddles just change `self.position = self.position.move(0, -1)` to `self.position = self.position.move(0, -2)`

Comment: Yes, but they still move at half speed only when both are moving, when only one bumper is active it runs twice as fast.

Comment: take off the time delay and adjust the speed back to 1

Comment: Taking off the time delay worked! Thanks. One last thing though, when both bumpers are moving, when one stops, the other stops too.

Comment: Please, never never ever mix `pygame.event.get()` with `pygame.key.get_pressed()`. In your code, you only check if a key is being pressed if there's an event in the event queue, and if there are multiple events in the queue, you end up calling e.g. `hitterA.moveUp()` multiple times. Just use `pygame.key.get_pressed()` *outside* the `for` loop. Otherwise, the bumpers will move faster if you e.g. move the mouse rapidly, since that would create a bunch of events in the event queue, and for each of those events you call `hitterX.moveXX`...

Comment: Hmmmm, that makes sense. What would be a better way to format it? And would this fix the problem with one bumper effecting the other?